# ImageField and several sizes in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new at Django (and Python) and was wondering about the ImageField property of a class. My example is about users of my website. I need 3 sizes of each picture of a user:
* user1-200-200.png
* user1-120-120.png
* user1-60-60.png

Of course I want only 1 file input type.
Should I create 3 properties and resize the one from the form for all properties:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    avatar_200_200 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    avatar_120_120 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    avatar_60_60 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
```

Can I use no property and do what I did in PHP, resize the images several times, move them to the proper folder and in the website, use the session to find them (I always rename the images and transform them to png).

I don't know what to do and what's possible to do and what's the best. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that but you will have to reimplement some of built-in django features like file uploading, storage support, width/height calculating/saving etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. As a beginner, if I can avoid doing that, it would be great. What do you think about using a package, such as https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/sorl-thumbnail/ ?
I don't know how it works, but it seems to be a good practice, doesn't it?

Comment: I used `sorl.thumbnail` a lot - it is very easy to use and works perfectly :-)  And besides of generating of thumbnails is has some helper fields/mixins to integrate into django's admin.

Comment: OK, will try that. Can't wait even if it's a bit complicated to start over with new elements I don't understand. Let's go!